# Why does aliasing commands not work when in a new subshell?

Tags: bash, alias

For example, if I do

```
alias a=clear
```

Typing in "a" will clear the terminal.

But when I write "a" in a subshell, it won't recognize the aliasing.

Why does it do this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/319538/aliases-in-subshell-child-process

Answer (score 2):

When you create an alias in your current shell it isn't saved when you execute a new bash process. If you want to save your aliases put them in your .bashrc (which should be located in your home directory). That way every time you execute a new bash shell it will load your configuration from that file.